# Xamarin Razor template in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, razor, xamarin

Is it possible to create a Razor template in a Xamarin.iOS/Android or Windows project in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Try In Xamarin.Android RightClick On Folder Asset And Select AddNewItem Add Preprocessed RazorPage.
I Think This Work In VisuallStudio 2013 be done.

Answer (score -2):

There is a section in the Xamarin docs on [Building HTML views using Razor Templates](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/razor_html_templates/).  There is also a [sample app](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/RazorTodo) available that demonstrates using Razor in a mobile app.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is whether there is any template available from Visual Studio 2013.